# Collision detection and solution causes teleportation on corners

Tags: collision-detection, python, collision-resolution, collision-avoidance

I am making my own game engine on Python and I got stuck with collision between objects.

```
# If we go Right
if (collision_rect.right >= object_collision_rect.left) and \
        (collision_rect.left <= object_collision_rect.left):
    if (collision_rect.bottom > object_collision_rect.top) and \
            (collision_rect.top < object_collision_rect.bottom):
        if self.acceleration.x > 0:
            self.acceleration.x = 0
            moving.x = object_collision_rect.left - collision_rect.right


 # Bottom
 if (collision_rect.bottom >= object_collision_rect.top) and \
         (collision_rect.top <= object_collision_rect.top):
     if (collision_rect.right > object_collision_rect.left) and \
             (collision_rect.left < object_collision_rect.right):
         if self.acceleration.y > 0:
             self.acceleration.y = 0
             moving.y = object_collision_rect.top - collision_rect.bottom
```

There are two more for left and top.

It makes teleporting on corners. And if we change the second conditions from < > to <= >=, we get teleporting on edges, if we have acceleration x and y both != 0

Comment: Hmm, first of all I would compartimentalize this far more (if just for readability)
Make one method for collision detection
Then one to find out the direction of the collision
And you call both those in  the method that handles movement.
That way you decouple the detection from the actual movement and are more likely to find the source of the teleportation

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. First of all I made collision detection function for readability, then I made collision for each axis apart.

```
self.collision(objects_around, Vector2D(self.acceleration.x, 0))
self.collision(objects_around, Vector2D(0, self.acceleration.y))

def collision(self, objects, acceleration):
    if not self.collision:
        return

    self.position += acceleration
    collision_rect = self.get_collision_rect()

    for object in objects:
        if not object.isCollision or self.id_ == object.id_:
            continue
        object_collision_rect = object.get_collision_rect()
        if not collision_rect.intersects(object_collision_rect):
            continue

        if acceleration.x > 0:
            self.position.x += object_collision_rect.left - collision_rect.right
        elif acceleration.x < 0:
            self.position.x += object_collision_rect.right - collision_rect.left

        if acceleration.y > 0:
            self.position.y += object_collision_rect.top - collision_rect.bottom
        elif acceleration.y < 0:
            self.position.y += object_collision_rect.bottom - collision_rect.top
```